# how to use web.php in laravel to a login with a react front-end

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication

I want to separate front-end (react) to back-end(Laravel), before I used web.php routes, but I don't know if I have those separate I must to use the API and do the login with passport, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use laravel only for back-end, look at laravel-lumen, it's a slim version of laravel with just the tools for the back-end and the doc contain all you need for api auth

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look of latest laravel 7 official **sanctum** package where you can use same repository for frontend & backend or separate also.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix